# Certain Flows with Few Actions Receive 429 Error

Tags: power-automate, ms-flow

I have 17 different flows that send individual emails from a range of 4-13 different people. These flows are scheduled to run every week day at 8:00 AM. Originally, instead of having a flow for each department, I had one flow that sent to all of those people but after about 25 minutes the flow would time out.

Now, with the individualized flows, some of them work, and some give the notification saying `Looks like your flow's operation is hitting an action limit designed to protect the connector service being called.`, and sends me to this throttle limit page. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendmail/#known-issues-and-limitations

In total the separate flows are sending about 63 emails. Why is it suggesting its reaching the connector limit? Do other flows have to do with this?

Actions in each flow:

`1) Recurrence (Runs at 8:00 every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, & Friday.`

`2) Get items from a list that has person's name in a person or group field, then a field with their department (for each flow, query filter by that department to only return those users in that department)`

`3) Apply to each (value from get items) --> Send an email notification v3 --> To Employee's email from the Person or Group field`

After reading the Concurrency, looping, and debatching limits section of this [Limits and configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#flow-limits) article, I thought it could be because all flows are running concurrently at 8:00 AM, but it states that the concurrence of Apply to Each actions can run between 1-50 in parallel

Comment: how many actions your individual flow has? Also, are you using the same user connection across all the flows? Each action is considered an API call. you can check if you are not exceeding the per minute API call threshold as all your flows start at the same time and run with the same user account.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Automate, most actions are counted and pooled per User, so from a Licence viewpoint, there is a limit on number of call per day for each service you use.